# Add online javadoc to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to add OrientDB javadoc to my Netbeans project but I can't get it to work...

Javadoc URL:
http://www.orientechnologies.com/javadoc/latest/

(but I've also tried http://www.orientechnologies.com/javadoc/latest/index.html)

I have all my JAR files in a library, call it myLibrary. This includes both OrientDB related JARs as well as other JARs. They are all added via the Classpath (the sources tab is empty). myLibrary has been added to the project in question.

I've tried to add the Javadoc in the following two ways:

```
1.) Tools -> Libraries -> myLibrary -> JavaDoc -> Add URL..
2.) Tools -> Java Platforms -> JDK 1.8 -> Javadoc -> Add URL..
```

My hopes for the second option are low, but I was getting desperate..

As you probably understood, I'm not using maven or anything similar.
What am I doing wrong?